# Segues initiated directly from view controllers must have an identifier

Tags: xcode, storyboard

I'm seeing this warning in a project with regard to storyboard:
warning: Unsupported Configuration: Segues initiated directly from view controllers must have an identifier.

Segues initiated directly from view controllers must have an identifier.
Ideas on how to know specifically which segues?

Answer (score 2):

1. Open Storyboard
2. Search for **push segue to** or **segue to** in bottom of search area like image attached
   [image]

Hope it helps.